# How to tighten a circular saw without a spindle / arbor lock?

Tags: circular-saw

I have an older Black & Decker Sawcat #987. It does not appear to have any way of locking the spindle that I can find.

How are you supposed to tighten down the blade bolt if you can't hold the spindle from turning? It gets semi-tight and then the spindle just turns. The blade is still free to rotate at this point. I don't think there is enough friction to run the motor to snug it up that way.

I am aware of methods to loosen the bolt without a lock (hold the blade with block of wood, sharply applied torque, etc.) but these don't seem to apply when tightening.

(I feel like I may be missing something obvious because this seems like a ridiculous problem!)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have used a screwdriver.

UNPLUG THE SAW.

finger tighten the bolt as far as you can, set the screwdriver across the fence and slide it into the teeth so that  blade tooth is up against the shaft of the screwdriver and can not turn. This is usually enough to get the arbor bolt to snug up enough so that it pinches the arbor onto the blade. Perhaps a vise grip would work as well to grab the blade.

Comment: Some blades have a hole in them that a screw driver will fit through and catch on the frame this is a little easier than on the teeth less chance of slipping.

Answer (score -1):

Screw driver trick works. The blade will tighten itself once there's a load on it